# XCODE - Select a provisioning profile for the "Debug" build configuration in the project editor

Tags: ios, xcode

I do not have a developer account. I signed in with my Apple ID account. How can I resolve these mistakes?[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

select your project name then in general tab check the Automatically manage signing
this will create a provisioning profile for your project.

if you want to build and run your app on the real device then the select team as well.[image]

Comment: remember you can if you do not have developer account then your provisioning is valid for next 6 days only after that your app not gone open in real device for that you have to run the app on the real device with new provisioning profile

Comment: I chose the same options as yours and I get the same mistakes again

Comment: please provide a screenshot and make sure you have selected a team in my case I don't